# Convert float64 3-D array to float32 3-D array in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I tried the following, but none of them worked

```
A = zeros(2,2,2)
A[:,:,1] = [1 2; 3 4]
A[:,:,2] = [10 20; 30 40]

for i=1:size(A,1)
    convert(Array{Float32,2}, A[i,:,:])
end

print(typeof(A))
```

Output: `Array{Float64,3}`

```
convert(Array{Float32,3}, A)
print(typeof(A))
```

Output: `Array{Float64,3}`

```
map(y->(Float32,y), A)
print(typeof(A))
```

Output: `Array{Float64,3}`

I can't even convert the array of Float64 to an array of `Int`:

```
for i=1:size(A,1)
    round.(Int,  A[i,:,:])
end

print(typeof(A))
```

Output: `Array{Float64,3}`

Anything else I can do to try to convert this from `Array{Float64,3}` to `Array{Float32,3}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
A = zeros(2,2,2)
A[:,:,1] = [1 2; 3 4]
A[:,:,2] = [10 20; 30 40]
```

Use `Float32.(A)`

```
julia> A=Float32.(A)
2×2×2 Array{Float32,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1.0  2.0
 3.0  4.0

[:, :, 2] =
 10.0  20.0
 30.0  40.0

julia> print(typeof(A))
Array{Float32,3}
```

The '.' operator for broadcasting the operation element-wise.

Answer (score 0):

```
    julia> x = zeros(3,3,3)
    3×3×3 Array{Float64,3}:
    [:, :, 1] =
     0.0  0.0  0.0
     0.0  0.0  0.0
     0.0  0.0  0.0

    [:, :, 2] =
     0.0  0.0  0.0
     0.0  0.0  0.0
     0.0  0.0  0.0

    [:, :, 3] =
     0.0  0.0  0.0
     0.0  0.0  0.0
     0.0  0.0  0.0

    julia> x .|> Float32
    3×3×3 Array{Float32,3}:
    [:, :, 1] =
     0.0  0.0  0.0
     0.0  0.0  0.0
     0.0  0.0  0.0

    [:, :, 2] =
     0.0  0.0  0.0
     0.0  0.0  0.0
     0.0  0.0  0.0

    [:, :, 3] =
     0.0  0.0  0.0
     0.0  0.0  0.0
     0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `convert` syntax is close. You can just do:

```
B = convert(Array{Float32},A)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the way you're calling `convert`. It works completely fine.

But `convert` doesn't work *in-place*. Instead it creates a *new* array, which you have to assign to an output variable (it also works if you re-assign the new array back to `A`):

```
julia> A = rand(2,2,2);

julia> B = convert(Array{Float32, 3}, A); # this does *not* change A

julia> typeof(A) # A is not changed
  Array{Float64,3}

julia> typeof(B) # this is the converted array
  Array{Float32,3}

julia> A = convert(Array{Float32, 3}, A);

julia> typeof(A)
  Array{Float32,3}
```

You can also use the other suggested solutions, such as `Float32.(A)`, but that is not your problem.